# Create `npm publish` zipped artifact

Tags: npm, tar

I have a package that I'm building using a CI server. I can zip my whole directory using something like `tar -zcvf filename.tgz .` but I don't want to include the files in my .npmignore. For example, I don't want to include `/src`, `.gitignore`, `junit.xml`, and a few other directories.

How can I create an artifact that looks like the published version of the package?

I guess one solution is to use `--exclude`.

`tar --exclude="./src" --exclude=".gitignore" --exclude="junit.xml" -zcvf filename.tgz .`

Or use `--include`:

`tar -zcvf filename.tgz --include="./lib" --include=".babelrc.js" --include=".eslint.js" --include="package.json"`

However, I don't like either of these solutions because I have to manually update two places (.npmignore, and this command) every time I add a file/directory to the project.

Comment: How do you feel about using a tool like https://www.npmjs.com/package/tartifacts?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is `-X`.

.npmignore

```
.git/*
__mocks__/*
.vscode/*
coverage/*
src/*
node_modules/*
junit.xml
```

Notice that I am including `node_modules/` and `.git`. `npm publish` already doesn't include them, but we don't want them in our archive. We can now exclude whatever file/directory we want.

`tar -X .npmignore -cvf filename.tar .`

I noticed that directories we are excluding doesn't include the contents of the directory, but still includes the directory itself, just empty. How do we not include the directory at all? I tried `.git/` and it didn't exclude any files.